# Assign same helm value to more than one targets

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am working on a Helm chart, which should spin up a database as well a client which consumes the database. To avoid redundancy I only wanna provide one value (username, password), which should be assigned to the client and the DB.
And only if it's not the default value, all other values should be overridden.

So, when I create the chart and pass a different value to the `db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD` it should override the `users.env.DB_PASSWORD` as well

```
helm install --debug --dry-run --set db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
```

Here a short snippet from my values.yml

```
db:
  env:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "default123"

users:
  env:
    DB_PASSWORD: "default123"
```

I think I have to do this somehow int the `_helpers.tpl` file.
Something like this, but it is not working.

```
{{- define "db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD" -}}
{{- default "password123" -}}
{{- end -}}

{{- if ne db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD "default123" }} # => This line causes the error
{{- define "users.env.DB_PASSWORD" -}}
{{- default .Values.db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end }}
```

ERROR:

```
unexpected <define> in command
```

Please point me to the right direction, thank you

Comment: BTW: users.env.DB_PASSWORD is also not overwritten

Answer (score 0):

You might restructure this to have a *single* setting of that password and then inject it into multiple places.  The Helm `values.yaml` file could include

```
databasePassword: default123
```

and then individual Deployments' YAML files could include

```
env:
  - name: DB_PASSWORD
    value: {{ .Values.databasePassword | quote }}
```

For the specific logic you're asking about, the important thing is that `{{ define }}` must always be at the top level (you can't conditionally define a template); also, the templates and values settings are in different namespaces (you can't use `define` to change a `.Values` value).  You can write a template that always produces some specific password value, choosing a source for it:

```
{{- define "users.env.DB_PASSWORD" -}}
{{- if ne .Values.db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD "default123" -}}
{{- .Values.db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- .Values.users.env.DB_PASSWORD -}}
{{- end -}}
```

and call it in the Deployment template:

```
env:
  - name: DB_PASSWORD
    value: {{ include "users.env.DB_PASSWORD" . | quote }}
```

It's important to note here that `default` takes *two* parameters; calling `db.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD` as you've shown it will produce an error because it doesn't know what value to apply that default to.